# Use PayPal to execute payments inside own website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I would know if PayPal provides the possibility to execute payments avoiding exiting from own website.
In other words, using PayPal API is it possibile to execute payments inside the own website without being redirected to PayPal servers?

Thanks

Comment: I hope not! I wouldn't want my PayPal credentials being routed through your servers!

Comment: I wouldn't want you to design my website BonyT because the standard PayPal payment process is so unbelievably terrible that it turns many people away from transacting online.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is called [Website Payments Pro](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_pro).

You must handle all of the integration on your end, including installing an SSL certificate.

Comment: That still sends you to the PayPal website for payment, but you can customise the pages with company info.

Comment: @BonyT That depends on your implementation. With Website Payments Pro, you can utilize the many PayPal API operations that would allow you to seamlessly integrate PayPal into the background of your own site. Such as the `DoDirectPayment` API operation, you are able to gather the customer's billing information, send it to PayPal, and PayPal will return whether the transaction was *SUCCESS* or *FAILURE*, without the customer leaving the site.

Comment: @BonyT - Payments **Pro** -- not to be confused with Payments _standard_. Standard is the typical "Pay Now" button you see across the web. You would never know the payment gateway is PayPal with a fully integrated system using Website Payments Pro. Its functionality is similar to Authorize.net's AIM, whereas Website Payments Standard is similar to Authorize.net's Simple Checkout.

Comment: Interesting - although I personally wouldn't shop at such a site using PayPal - I accept the tiny risk that using a CC online can result in fraudulent activity. Having my PayPal credentials compromised is rather more serious - I'd be interested to know if any major retailers use this mechanism, as I doubt I'm unique in this caution.

Comment: @BonyT. I don't think anyone would expect you to enter your PayPal credentials into a random website: instead, you use your credit card, and PayPal are used to process the payment. There are many companies which offer this service, and you would never know which any given site is using. (PayPal offer this service only in the USA, the UK, and Canada. In Ireland, Realex Payments is the main player. And there are loads of others.)

Comment: Nick, you might add that this service is available only in **the USA, the UK, and Canada**. If you're anywhere else in the world, you'll need to use a different provider.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement hztera's answer, here is some helpful documentation to accomplish integrating PayPal into your site:

- [Website Payments Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro)
- [DoDirectPayment API Operation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment)
- [Pay Flow](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayment)
- [NVP API Basics](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPNVPAPIBasics)
- [Sample Code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)